# Node-specific component for graphs

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a name for the set of nodes which can be reached from a given node in a graph, similar to a node-specific component? Or in the words of @mark-s in the comments: the vertex set of the component of that vertex.

[Reachbility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability) is not the right term because it is defined as the reachability refers to the ability to get from one vertex to another within a graph, not as a set of vertices that can be reached.

The Python graph library [`networkx` calls it](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.node_connected_component.html#networkx.algorithms.components.node_connected_component) *node connected component*, but I cannot find any literature using that term

In [time-varying graphs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.0009.pdf) the set of vertices which can be reached in a time-respecting manner is called *horizon*. I am looking for the equivalent for time-aggregated, static graphs.

Comment: I'm not a graph theorist, but it's not clear to me what you mean by "node-specific" [component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_%28graph_theory%29). Are you asking for a word for "the vertex set of the component of that vertex"/"the set of vertices a given one is connected to"?

Comment: Thanks for commenting and yes!

Comment: I don't think this has a standard name. I have seen multiple papers where they say something like "let C(v) be the component containing the vertex v."  See e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.0484.pdf or https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.2636.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot! Maybe horizon is a good term. :)